# Prove T is continuous on $C^{(1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

let $x(t)$ function defined on $C_{[a,b]}$ defined on [$a,b$]

$T_{1}(x)$ = $\phi$[$x(t_{0}),x(t_{1}),...,x(t_{n})$] and $\phi$ is continuous.

$T_{2}(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{1}$ $\sqrt{1+ (x'(t))^{2}}$ $dt$

$T_{3}(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{1}$ |$x'(t)$| $dt$

Prove $T_{1}$ is continuous on $C_{[a,b]}$ and  $T_{2}$ , $T_{3}$ are discontinuous on $C_{[a,b]}$ but continuous on $C^{1}_{[a,b]}$

I showed that $T_{2}$ , $T_{3}$ are discontinuous on $C_{[a,b]}$ by giving examples.

First, for $T_{1}$ be continuous I need to check $\forall$ $x \in C_{[a,b]}$ for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $\forall y \in C_{[a,b]}$, $\sup|x-y| <\delta $ implies $|T_{1}(x)$ -$T_{1}(y)| < \epsilon$, so I wrote the definition $\phi$ and I want to get $\sup|x-y| < \delta$  by using $0<\sqrt{(x(t_{0})-y(t_{0}))^{2}+...+(x(t_{n})-y(t_{n}))^{2}} <\delta$ in the definition of $\phi$ which I couldn't.

Second, for $C^{1}_{[a,b]}$ we are using metric $d(x,y)= \sup_{t}(|x(t)-y(t)|+|x'(t)-y'(t)|)$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. Here what makes things difficult for me is square root in the integral. I can't get rid of this because $\sqrt{1+(x'(t))^{2}}$ should be integral in $T_{2}$

Third, Now I solved finally $T_{3}$ is continuous on $C^{1}_{[a,b]}$.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to have $(x'(t))^2$ in $T_2$? (Otherwise it may not be defined, if $x'(t) < -1$.)

Comment: yes thank you. Now I edited.

Comment: How are you expecting to  define $T_2,T_3$ for non differentiable functions...?

Comment: I am not expecting indeed. Take $x_{0}(t)=0$ and $x_{n}(t)= 1/n $ $sin2\pi n t$ then $sup|x_{n} - x_{0}|$= 1/n goes to $0$ but $T_{2}>4$ for all n and $T_{2}(x_{0})= 1 $. Thus, $T_{2}$ is not continuous on $C_{[a,b]}$. am I wrong ?

Comment: I think Peter's point is that $T_2,T_3$ are only  defined on a strict subset of $C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $T_1$ note that the function $\psi_t(x) = x(t)$ satisfies $|\psi_t(x)-\psi_t(y)| \le \|x-y\|_\infty$, hence since $\phi$ is continuous at $(x(t_0),...,x(t_n))$, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $z \in B((x(t_0),...,x(t_n)), \delta)$, then $|\phi((x(t_0),...,x(t_n))) -\phi(z)| < \epsilon$. (I am using the $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ norm $\|z\| = \max_k |z_k|$ for convenience.)

Now choose $y \in B(x,\delta)$, then since $(y(t_0),...,y(t_n)) \in B((x(t_0),...,x(t_n)), \delta)$ we see that $|\phi((x(t_0),...,x(t_n))- \phi((y(t_0),...,y(t_n))| < \epsilon$.

For $T_2$, note that $\sqrt{1+a^2}-\sqrt{1+b^2} = { (a+b)(a-b) \over \sqrt{1+a^2}+\sqrt{1+b^2}}$. (In particular, we have $|\sqrt{1+a^2}-\sqrt{1+b^2}| \le |a-b|$.)

For $T_3$, note that $||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$.

Comment: thank you so much. for $T_{3}$ I solved exactly the same way. now I will check $T_{2}$ and $T_{1}$.

Comment: I don't know why but I can't use $||.||_{\infty}$ to get $sup|x-y|$ $<$ $\delta$ by using $y \in  B(x,\delta)$. Can you elaborate this a little bit ? ok I showed $T_{2}$ is continuous.

Comment: There are two norms floating around here, so some notational care is needed. I use $\|z\| = \max_k |z_k|$ and $\|x\|_\infty = \max_{t \in [a,b]} |x(t)|$. Note that $y \in B(x,\delta)_\infty$ **iff** $\|x-y\|_\infty < \delta$. Also, if $\|x-y\|_\infty < \delta$, then $\|(x(t_0),...,x(t_n))-(y(t_0),...,y(t_n))\| <\delta$. Does this help?

Comment: It might be slightly easier from a notational perspective to let $\eta: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be given by $\eta(x) = (x(t_0),...,x(t_n))$. Then we have $\|\eta(x)-\eta(y)\| \le \|x-y\|_\infty$, hence it is continuous. Then note that $T_1 = \phi \circ \eta$. Since $\phi, \eta$ are continuous, so is their composition.